# Draw line between two draggable points in andorid

Tags: android

I want to have two points which can be dragged from one point to another point and there will be a line which will always remain connected to each other and will change according to the point.

plz suggest me something or any example code

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you read the excellent android development documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this](http://roosmaa.net/drawing-beautiful-bezier-lines/)

[image]

the actual drawing of the lines in the onDraw method would look something like this:

```
Path p = new Path();
Point mid = new Point();
// ...
Point start = ...;
Point end = ...;
mid.set((start.x + end.x) / 2, (start.y + end.y) / 2);

// Draw line connecting the two points:
p.reset();
p.moveTo(start.x, start.y);
p.quadTo((start.x + mid.x) / 2, start.y, mid.x, mid.y);
p.quadTo((mid.x + end.x) / 2, end.y, end.x, end.y);

canvas.drawPath(p, pLineBorder);
canvas.drawPath(p, pLine);
```